# Replacing values in a column with the least value in a group using case statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table `table1`

```
pid_x   pid_y   count
  a       b       5
  a       c      10
  b       a      20
  c       e       3
  d       g       7
  e       f       10
  e       b       20
```

Also I have a `master_table`
 which consists details

```
master_id          pid     price_pid
    a               a1       10
    a               b1       20
    a               c1       30
    b               d1       40
    b               e1       50
    c               f1       60
    d               g1       70
```

for the values in pid_x which are equal to values in master_id i want to replace that pid_x and pid_y with the least priced `pid` for that master_id

i.e final result.

```
pid_x   pid_y    count
  a1      d1      5
  a1      f1      10
  d1      a1      20
  f1      e       3
  g1      g       7
```

and so on.

i wanted a case statment for this.

`select pidx,pid_y,count from table1 A
INNER JOIN master_table m1
ON CASE WHEN A.pid_x = B.master_id then replace that pid_x with cheapest pid dor that mater_id......`

Answer (score 0):

I really wish MySQL supported CTEs to avoid rewriting the same subquery twice. But, try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.pid, t1.pid_x) pid_x,
  COALESCE(t3.pid, t1.pid_y) pid_y,
  SUM(t1.count) COUNT
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT t1.*
  FROM master_table t1
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT master_id, MIN(pid) pid FROM master_table GROUP BY master_id
    ) t2
  ON t1.master_id  = t2.master_id
  AND t1.pid       = t2.pid
  ) t2 ON t1.pid_x = t2.master_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT t1.*
  FROM master_table t1
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT master_id, MIN(pid) pid FROM master_table GROUP BY master_id
    ) t2
  ON t1.master_id  = t2.master_id
  AND t1.pid       = t2.pid
  ) t3 ON t1.pid_x = t3.master_id
GROUP BY COALESCE(t2.pid, t1.pid_x),
  COALESCE(t3.pid, t1.pid_y) ;
```